Is it possible to use SharePoint CSOM Powershell to take ownership of Ghost files?
Within the SharePoint 2016/2019 interface it is possible to take ownership of "Ghost files" via the library settings "Manage files with no checked in version" report.
It isn't practical to do this across thousands of libraries so I wanted to do it via Powershell. That way I can take ownership, download the files, delete them from SharePoint and then dispose of the downloaded versions at my leisure.
It would have to work for SharePoint 2016/2019 on-premise (preferably using CSOM) and run under Site Collection Admin permissions. I can't run PowerShell on the SharePoint server itself as I am not a Farm Admin.
It is not an option to force a check-in as the users have, in 99% of cases, not provided the mandatory metadata.
Does anyone know if this is even possible?
I've unsuccessfully looked for a solution via search engines.
